# Why do objects have a Natural Frequency?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, spectroscopy, resonance, vibrations

Why should an object even have a [natural frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_frequency), why not vibrate at any other frequency? This just sounds nonsensical.

Comment: It not only sounds nonsensical, it is nonsensical.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that an object can only vibrate at its natural frequency, and that’s not the case. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you asking about _[harmonic oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator)_? If not, then what other kind of object and natural frequency are you asking about?

Comment: @PM2Ring You comment is incorrect. Any system (linear or nonlinear) whose internal energy density distribution can change with time can oscillate. "Oscillation" doesn't only mean "Simple Harmonic Motion."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Harmonic oscillators can "vibrate" at any frequency. The question is whether the OP is asking about *free* (or *unforced*) vibration - and if he/she *is* asking about free vibration, it is an excellent question IMO, aside from that fact that it wasn't asked clearly.

Comment: @aleph Fair enough.

Comment: @my2cts It is *not* nonsensical. Think about a rocking chair, a tuning fork, the air in an organ pipe, or the fact that the light from a sodium streetlamp is yellow and not blue. Objects do indeed have natural or resonant frequencies at which they most easily oscillate, determined by their strength  internal or external forces, their mass, the geometry of their container, etc.

Comment: Wow, so much is wrong in this comment section. @alephzero "Harmonic oscillators can "vibrate" at any frequency" No way. They can only vibrate at specific frequencies.

Comment: @G. Smith None of this makes sense. A rocking chair in free fall does not rock. And what a bout a non-rocking chair? And sodium atoms can probably also be made to emit blue light, or infrared. A tuning fork has harmonics as well. And is air in an organ pipe an object ?

Comment: By Newton's second law it will vibrate at the driving frequency of whatever periodic force is applied.  The "natural" frequencies arise from solving the inhomogeneous equation.  The resistance to motion is less at the so called natural frequencies so you will have large amplitude motion when driven at those frequencies.

Comment: Quite frankly the question is not only not well posed but opinion based.  Vote to close.

Comment: @my2cts Regardless of whether it makes sense to you, it is standard high-school physics. Wikipedia’s “natural frequency” article defines it this way: “Natural frequency, also known as eigenfrequency, is the frequency at which a system tends to oscillate in the absence of any driving or damping force.”

Comment: @ G. Smith I don't care what they teach at high school. A rotten tomato

Comment: @ G. Smith A rotten tomato does not have a natural frequency. If you restrict yourself to stiff objects without damping and a decent shape, such as church bells, then yes they have a natural frequency and a lot of harmonics. Perhaps I met just one person too many who thinks everything has a "frequency " .

Comment: @my2cts So why have you not posted an answer that the concept of natural frequency is nonsensical, in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

In everyday terms, commonplace objects are capable of resonance at some natural frequency if they possess 1) mass, 2) elasticity, and 3) little or no internal friction or damping. The mass allows them to temporarily store up energy by being in motion. The elasticity allows them to temporarily store up energy by being deformed. The absence of damping allows these two energy storage mechanisms to trade their energy back and forth repeatedly without losses, thereby establishing oscillation.

The amount of mass present compared to the amount of elasticity present sets the natural frequency that results. The amount of damping determines how long the oscillations persist after being set in motion.

Comment: Consider that damping do not exclude the existence of a natural frequency, it just shifts it and reduces amplitudes.

Comment: Wonderful answer.